# How can I capture the "load" event by adding my own listener through ExecuteScript?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, selenium

I am trying to catch the `load` (not `onload`) event with Selenium.

My code looks like this (see comments) :

```
// d is my webdriver
// go to url
d.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(d, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

// create a function that add an element with id="my_123456789"
string javascript = 
   "my_readyFCT = function(){"
     + "alert('READY');"
     + "var e = document.createElement('div');"
     + "e.id = 'my_123456789';"
     + "document.body.appendChild(e);"
   + "};"
// call the function once 'load' event is fired
   + "window.addEventListener('load', my_readyFCT, false);"

((IJavaScriptExecutor)d).ExecuteScript(javascript);

// Selenium wait until the element with id "my_123456789" exists
wait.Until<IWebElement>(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("my_123456789")));
```

I always get a timeout exception (30 seconds) and I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Any idea ?

**Note** : I tried to execute the function `my_readyFCT` on it's own and it created the element with the correct id inserted into the DOM.

**EDIT**

Here is the javascript :

```
my_readyFCT = function() {
   alert('READY');
   var e = document.createElement('div');
   e.id = 'my_123456789';
   document.body.appendChild(e);
};
// call the function once 'load' event is fired
window.addEventListener('load', my_readyFCT, false);
```

**EDIT 2**

I must say I found a way to avoid the usual behavior of `GoToUrl` (which is to way for page load) :

```
var fb = new FirefoxBinary();
fb.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(4);
FirefoxProfile fp = new FirefoxProfile();
// 'unstable' allow us to avoid the implicit wait in GoToUrl
fp.SetPreference("webdriver.load.strategy", "unstable");
d = new FirefoxDriver(fb, fp, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
```

And when I want to change url :

```
d.Manage().Timeouts().SetPageLoadTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0));
try {
   d.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
}
catch(WebDriverException) /* will be thrown everytime */ 
{ }

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(d, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
/*
*  ...
*   ETC. See code above
*  ...
*/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do cannot be done. The documentation for [`GoToUrl`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_INavigation_GoToUrl.htm) (which is `get` for Java and Python and probably other languages that Selenium supports) explicitly says that it blocks "until the load is complete".

You can test it. Take the following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/xhtml; charset=utf-8"/>
    <script>
      window.addEventListener("load", function () {
          window.loaded_inline = true;
      });
    </script>
   </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

And run the following Selenium script. Sorry, I don't do C# so this is Python. It should not be too hard to understand:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("file:///tmp/t2/index.html")  # This gets the page above.

# This checks whether the load handler in the page was called.
print "Inline:", driver.execute_script("return window.loaded_inline")

driver.set_script_timeout(2)

# This is an asynchronous script. It will end when the load event is
# emitted by the browser. Or timeout if the event does not happen.
driver.execute_async_script("""
var done = arguments[0];
window.addEventListener('load', done, false);
""")

driver.quit()
```

When I execute this, I get `Inline: True` and then a timeout. You can increase the timeout as long as you want, it will never change the result.

What this indicates is that the `load` event happens before `get` returns, and by then it is too late to add any more listeners to `load`.

#### What About Making the Page Load Return Immediately?

It does not work either. First, it seems to me that the fact that you have to set `webdriver.load.strategy` to the value `unstable` ought to be a clue that maybe that's not something, you know, stable. That setting is [marked "beta"](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver#-Beta-_load_fast_preference) in the documentation. The doc also says:

> This may cause immediate find's [sic] to break, so please be sure to use an implicit or explicit wait too.

The use-case they are talking about there is load the page immediately and then search for an element on it. **This search won't be able to complete until the HTML is fully loaded, which means that `load` will have happened already.**

If you do try to run a script *before* finding an element, then the **script does not execute at all.**

Comment: I already found a workaround to avoid this problem : I explicitly say selenium not to wait for `GoToUrl` not to wait for page load ends. I start with `FirefoxProfile fp = new FirefoxProfile(); fp.SetPreference("webdriver.load.strategy", "unstable");` and before `GoToUrl` : `d.Manage().Timeouts().SetPageLoadTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0)); try { d.Navigate().GoToUrl(url); } catch(WebDriverException) /* will be thrown everytime */ { }`

Comment: Hum. I see, I need to find something else. Thank you for your answer